# How select postgresql jsonb column with jpql and map it to a Model?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, jsonb

I create a postgresql table as follow sql:

```
create table if not exists mytable(id serial primary key, commit_id varchar(20),
   links jsonb)
```

No I have a model class in a spring boot application as follow:

```
public class Link{
    String name;
    String url;
    
    // getters and setters
}

public class Links extends ArrayList<Link> {}

public class FeatureLink{
    String feaureId;
    Links links;
    
    // getters and setters
}
```

I do inserting data as follow:

```
String stringLinks = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(featureLink.links)
String sql = "INSERT INTO mytable(feature_id, links)values('" + 
              featureLink.featureId + "','" + stringLinks + "')"
```

Now, I want to query to the table as follow:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql).getResultList()
```

It occures:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111

How can I query to mytable with jpa native query and map it to `FeatureLink`?

**Note:** Because of project structure, I can't define `FeatureLink` as entity

Comment: You have to implement UserType for custom  type here is example https://thorben-janssen.com/persist-postgresqls-jsonb-data-type-hibernate/

Comment: I guess your best approach will jdbc because you can't create FeatureLink as entity.

You can use jdbcTemplate in spring framework.

Comment: Also don't extend ArrayList